# Error show if there is a duplication of record in MySQL using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, navicat

Good day! Can someone help me fix my code? I would like to show an error message if there is a duplication of record. For example, I entered a username "admin" but it is already in my database so it should show a message saying "Username already exists!". Otherwise, If the username isn't used yet then it will be added in my database. I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and Navicat for MySQL
Here is my code:

conn.Open()

```
        Dim qadd As String = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE uname='" & txt_uname.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(qadd, conn)
        Dim data As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If data.Read Then
            If data(0) = txt_uname.Text Then
                MsgBox("User " & data(0) & " already exists! ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            Else
                Dim qstr As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (uname, pword, ulvl) VALUES ('" & txt_uname.Text & "' , '" & txt_pword1.Text & "' , '" & txt_pword2.Text & "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uname = '" & txt_uname.Text & "'"
                Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(qstr, conn)
                Dim dat As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
                MsgBox("User has been added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                txt_uname.Clear()
                txt_pword1.Clear()
                txt_pword2.Clear()
                txt_uname.Focus()
            End If
        End If

        conn.Close()
```

Comment: Couple different approaches to this.  One you're already doing, so not really sure what the question is.  Second option is to make a unique index in the db, that will cause and exception when attempting to insert a duplicate record that you can catch and handle as required.

Comment: Also, read up on parameterize your sql commands.  Whole lot easier to work with than the string concatenations that you currently have

Comment: My code works and when I'm entering a username in my registration form that is already existing in my database, it says that the username already exists. But my problem is when I'm trying to enter a new username that has no record in my database, It does nothing.

Comment: Ahh, got you.  Alter your query to do a count of user records where user code = txt_uname.text.  Then use executescaler wich returns you the number of matching records.  The if 0 insert, else message

Comment: It's like the if statement only works but not the Else statement

Comment: Can you show me a sample of what you are saying? I'm new to vb.net

Comment: So we have plain-text passwords, sql injection vulnerabilities, **and** leaving the connection hanging open if an exception is thrown. The trifecta!

Comment: Also: do you have a unique contraint, primary key, or similar set for the user name? I ask because that will change the answer.

Comment: My primary key in the table of my database is the uname

Comment: In that case, _skip the `SELECT` query completely_ and just run the `INSERT`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Still a lot of room for improvement, and I typed this out on my phone with no syntax checking, but think it should get you heading in the right direction.  Things for you to read up on is parametrising your query/insert statements and the Using keyword which can help with managing your db connections.

```
Dim qadd As String = "SELECT Count(uname)  FROM tbl_user WHERE uname='" & txt_uname.Text & "'"
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(qadd, conn)
Dim userCounter as int = cmd.ExecuteScaler
if userCounter > 0 then
  MsgBox("User " & data(0) & " already exists! ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
Else
  Dim qstr As String = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (uname, pword, ulvl) VALUES ('" & txt_uname.Text & "' , '" & txt_pword1.Text & "' , '" & txt_pword2.Text & "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uname = '" & txt_uname.Text & "'"
  Dim cm As New MySqlCommand(qstr, conn)
  Dim dat As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader
  MsgBox("User has been added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
  txt_uname.Clear()
  txt_pword1.Clear()
  txt_pword2.Clear()
  txt_uname.Focus()
End If
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works but when I'm trying to add a new user, it says that "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." in this part "Dim dat As MySqlDataReader = cm.ExecuteReader"

Comment: Well, that exception is pretty clear.  You’ve left a data connection open somewhere in your code.  That gets back to implementing your connections via Using clauses which will mop all that up for you

Comment: That’s great, really want to make it clear while it works this code has some serious flaws that you really should address before going too much further